# Paso de variables por referencia Javascript

Tags: javascript

He estado leyendo sobre los pasos de valor y referencia en un libro, y pues visto que estoy aprendiendo Javascript, me surgido la duda acerca de como se puede llevar a cabo esto.

He intentado lo siguiente:

```js
var X = 10;

function cambiar(variable){
  variable++;
}

cambiar(X);
alert(X);
```

Pero, al ejecutar el código, la variable **X** sigue teniendo el mismo valor, y no se cual es mi error, he buscado información, pero no encuentro nada muy claro al respecto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript, no soporta el paso de valores por referencia, al menos no para las variables.

Algo que podrias hacer es esto:

```js
var X = 10;

function cambiar(){
  X++;
}

cambiar(X);
alert(X);
```

Lo que cambia respecto a tu codigo, es el hecho de que ahora X es una variable global, lo unico que hacemos desde la funcion cambiar() es el incremento, no es necesario pasarle mas parametros.

#### Actualizacion

Existe un pequeño truco, para poder pasar un valor por referencia, y podria hacerse asi:

```js
var arreglo = [""];

function cambiar(variable){
  variable[0] = "FOO";
}

cambiar(arreglo);
alert(arreglo[0]);
```

Usando un arreglo, podemos modificar uno de sus indices, en este caso el indice 0 y usarlo posteriormente como un cambio del valor original.

Comment: Si me funciona, podría usarlo para un futuro, pero, ¿existe alguna manera de pasar algún valor por referencia?

Comment: He agregado un pequeño truco que podría servirte

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias amigo.

Comment: De nada, y bienvenido a la comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

Tal como dijo Daniel no hay modo, la manera es pasar un arreglo u objeto. Otras ideas:

## Pasar nombre de la variable

*Problema*: solo funciona para variables globales

```
var a=3;

function llamada(refVarGlobal){
    global[refVarGlobal]++;
}

console.log(a); // 3
llamada("a");
console.log(a); // 4
```

## Pasar nombre y contenedor

*Problema*: no se puede pasar local. Solo se pueden pasar propiedades de objetos, posiciones de arreglos y globales

```
var a=3;

function llamada(contenedor, refVar){
    contenedor[refVarGlobal]++;
}

console.log(a); // 3
llamada(global, "a");
console.log(a); // 4

function ClaseMia(){
    this.b=5;
    this.incrementar = function(){
        llamada(this, "b");
    }
}

var c = new ClaseMia()

console.log(c.b); // 5
c.incrementar();
console.log(c.b); // 6

function comun(){
    var contenedor = { e: 7 };
    var arreglo = [8];
    llamada(contenedor,"e");
    llamada(arreglo,8);
}
```

## Usar un objeto especial de referencia

*Problema*: solo se pueden pasar como referencia variables de la clase Ref.

```
function Ref(valorInicial){
    this.valor = valorInicial;
}

function llamada(ref){
    ref.valor++;
    ref.toString = function(){
        return ref.valor;
    }
}

var a = new Ref(3);

console.log(a); // 3
llamada(a);
console.log(a); // 4
```

Comment: Wow, ahora si me queda un poco mas claro, no sabia que con objetos tambien se podria. muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

En JavaScript no se puede forzar el paso de una variable por referencia como en otros lenguajes, pero algunos tipos de datos se pasan por defecto como referencia, estos son los `objetos` y los `arreglos`.

Es importante entender esto, ya que si no entiendes bien cuales tipos de datos se pasan por valor y cuales por referencia, puedes generar errores de sobre escritura no deseados en el contenido de las variables cuando se trata de estos tipos de elementos.

Veamos algunos ejemplos sobrescribiendo los datos:

```js
// Asignación con objetos 
let person_1 = {
    name: "César",
    age: 25
}
let person_2 =  person_1
person_2.name = 'Tutancamon'
person_2.age = 69
console.log("person 1", person_1)
console.log("person 2", person_2)


// Asignación con variables
let a = 20
let b = a
b = 500
console.log("a => ", a)
console.log("b => ", b)


// Asignación con array
let array_a = [10]
let array_b = array_a
array_b.push(999)
console.log("array_a => ", array_a)
console.log("array_b => ", array_b)

// Retorno de objeto desde función
function getMascot(){
    return {
        name: "Halsey",
        type: "Dog"
    }
}

let function_a = getMascot()
let function_b = getMascot()
function_b.name = "HolandaTerricolein"
console.log("from function_a => ", function_a)
console.log("from function_b => ", function_b)
```

WOW! Pero... ¿Qué pasó acá?

Lo que comentaba al principio, los objetos y arreglos al pasarse por referencia, si se modifican en la copia, igual se modificarán en el elemento original, mientras que las variables de tipos más "simples" como int, string, boolean u otras se pasarán por valor.

Hay un detalle importante y es que, cuando devolvemos uno de estos tipos de objetos que se pasan por referencia como retorno de una función, realmente obtendremos una copia por valor y no referencia, como se aprecia en el ejemplo superior.

Para finalizar, si algún día necesitas duplicar un objeto o array por valor no es necesario crear una función para retornar el valor, puedes utilizar el operador `...` como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
let person_1 = {
    name: "César",
    age: 25
}
let person_2 =  {... person_1}
person_2.name = 'Tutancamon'
person_2.age = 69
console.log("person 1", person_1)
console.log("person 2", person_2)
```

Entendiendo todo esto, creo que ya tienes la herramientas para solventar tu duda.